# Set property in mongoose object after query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose

while development of an API, I often need to set extra properties in the result of mongoDb query results. But I can't do it in a good way. For example

Model

```
const Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', { name: String,age:Number });
```

Query

```
Cat.findOne({age:2})  .then(
    cat=>{
        cat.breed="puppy";    
        console.log(cat)
    } )
```

here after I get the result from **mongoDb** I want to set the property of **breed** to the result , but I can't do it because the property is not defined in the **Schema**

So to set an extra property I use a hack

```
cat = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cat));
cat.favFood = "Milk"
```

I don't think its a good way to code. please give a better way of setting property and explain how the hack is working.

Answer (score 4):

Mongoose can actually do the conversion `toObject` for you with the `.lean()` option. This is preferred over manual conversion after the query (as [willis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9790759/willis) mentioned) because it **optimizes the mongoose query** by skipping all the conversion of the raw Mongo document coming from the DB to the Mongoose object, leaving the document as a plain Javascript object. So your query will look something similar to this:

```
Cat.findOne({age:2}).lean().then(
    cat=>{
        cat.breed="puppy";    
        console.log(cat)
    }
)
```

The result will be the same except that this will skip the Mongoose document-to-object conversion middleware. However, note that when you use `.lean()` you **lose all the Mongoose document class methods** like `.save()` or `.remove()`, so if you need to use any of those after the query, you will need to follow [willis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9790759/willis) answer.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`, you can call [`toObject`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toObject) to convert `cat` into a regular javascript object.

Mongoose objects have methods like `save` and `set` on them that allow you to easily modify and update the corresponding document in the database. Because of that, they try to disallow adding non-schema properties.

Alternatively, if you are trying to save these values you to the database, you may wish to look into the [strict option](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) (which is true by default).